# Do some XSLT only when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have a menu of `a` elements all of which get text from xml file using xslt:

```
<nav>
  <xsl:for-each select="package">
        <a href="#" onclick="generateContent('{@name}', this);"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a>
  </xsl:for-each>
</nav>
```

Now I would like to generate a `div` (and append it to website when a link would be clicked)  with its content generated from my xml file (using xslt like above).

What would be the best way to do it? My guess would be to do it from JS - from `generateContent(..)` function; but I am unaware if this is even possible and if I wouldn't be overcomplicating stuff that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're complicating a simple thing. In my way, you should generate all the html contents including menus and sub-items. Then do some javascript stuff to hide and show the sub-items whenever they should be shown. It requires you to use some CSS and javascript (maybe Jquery) things to get your work done.

It's not a good idea to call the xslt again from the onclick delegate because if you generate all the sub-items again and again, everytime user wants to see them, so you don't have the state all the time regardless of how hard it can be to implement. However in the way I understand your code it seems impossible (or very hard) to do such a thing.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed it seems to be suitable for my case. However - wouldn't this cripple the website when there would be large amounts of data in xml? I guess in that case one would need to represent it in a different way/with a different technique, eh?

Comment: I think you might wanna take a look at AJAX and calling web services from the client side. The problem is that the way you are using the XSLT to do the work is wrong. Simply XSLT is not made for these stuff however you can make it done. If you have lots of items, using AJAX would be the best way in my point of view.